# Are questions about very old Apple products on-topic?

Tags: support, site-scope

I'm about to buy this old PowerPC eMac just for nostalgia, some fun and for playing some old games I have.

I know there's a [beta site on retro computing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/).

However, is there any limit to age of Apple products in Ask Different's scope?

For example OS X versus older operating systems. Or Intel vs. PowerPC vs. Motorola 68040, etc.

To take two extreme examples, would questions about [Apple Lisa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Lisa) or the [PowerBook 100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerBook_100) be on-topic?

I realize that in such extreme cases it might be better to ask at the [beta site](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) I referred to earlier, but I'm asking if it's, strictly speaking, off-topic or on-topic.

And, if off-topic, where do you draw the line in terms of hardware and software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - Questions about Motorola and PPC era hardware are on topic.

Apple products and services are considered on topic without regard to them being beta, in production or withdrawn from sale and/or support.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Definitely read through the entire article above - there will be likely questions from that era that will be off topic if they have other faults:

- shopping for parts
- why did Apple choose 68000 processor instead of XYZ?
- [overly subjective questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) in general
- [How many Apple II computers were sold over their lifetime?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/459/over-its-lifetime-how-many-apple-2s-were-sold) (I include this since what's off topic here might be not only on-topic elsewhere, but well received and usefully documented and answered)

Comment: Cool! So even the Apple Lisa would be on-topic?

Comment: @Fiksdal we have apple II questions so no problem with new hardware :)

Comment: @Mark Nice :) And also cool that you consider it new, lol :) (jk, I know you meant old.)

Comment: I don't think anyone's tried to ask about anything older than the Apple I yet - so you should be just fine with something as new as the Lisa hardware system and software. Again - we aren't wikipedia for asking to find history - the question should have a practical aspect about how to do something specific.

Comment: bmike Sure, I'm talking about actual technical questions about use, software, etc. Anyway, cool. BTW, why do both you and @Mark refer to the Lisa as "new"?